# Java code for nShield Connect

Tags: java, pkcs#11, nshield

I am looking for a sample java code for connecting nShield Connect HSM by using PKCS11 library. RSA key is created on token slot 1 and soft token slot 2. Imported Certificate is on slot 1. I like to connect to HSM, read the slot 1 and find the certificate and sign the XML document.

Comment: Consider using [jacknji11](https://github.com/joelhockey/jacknji11) or [iaik pkcs11 provider](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core_Crypto_Toolkits/PKCS_11_Provider). If my memory serves me well, they both contain some sample code. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: How can I access nShield from Java remote? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late but here goes for those who have the same problem:

You can use [Sun PKCS#11 Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) or [IAIK](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core_Crypto_Toolkits/PKCS_11_Provider) to connect Java programs to the PKCS#11 libraries.

[This tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-cryptography/index.html) explains how to use JCE for cryptographic operations e.g. encrypt, sign, etc.